# "used to be" with a fact

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

In the situation where we have: 
*It used to be thought that...*

We use the past tense with the verb that follows since it's something in the past.
But what if the following is meant to be a fact?

I came into a question that says: 
It used to be thought that the Earth **is** flat.
It used to be thought that the Earth **was** flat.

Aside from the piece of information in the sentence, it *represents* a fact(Earth is flat) which makes the tense simple present. I believe that the correct one is *is*, am I right or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either one is valid.

Comment: Further, grammar has no place for "facts".

(I don't follow '… the piece of information in the sentence.')

Going a stage further than the actual wording, this is almost about direct and reported speech… 

It used to be thought: "The Earth is flat".

It used to be thought that the Earth was flat.